# отображение спецсимволов в виде кодов на golang

Tags: golang

Открываю файл os.stdutil, но спецсимволы отображаются такого вида &#amp и др.
Как мне вывести файл,как он есть на самом деле?

Comment: Проблема не ясна. Что ещё за `os.stdutil`? Если надо конвертнуть из `&amp;` в `&` то используй [html.UnescapeString](https://godoc.org/html#UnescapeString).

Comment: Ну просто открываю html файл через os.Open и вывожу потом в браузер пользователю,но почему-то вместо тегов получаю код самого тега,а не тег

Comment: Может дело в `content-type`?

Comment: о..может.спасибо. попробую,как дома буду. Тоесть поставить utf-8;text/html ?

Comment: Да просто глянь какие заголовки в браузере. Скорее всего просто браузер не понимает это как HTML, а как `text/plain` или `application/octet-stream` какой-нибудь... Да должен быть `text/html`.